# QGIS Two people working on one shapefile at once?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

Is it possible for two people to work on the same shapefile at the same time?

Atm we split the data into two shapes and merge them after editing (version 2.12), but we are looking for a more comfortable, easier way to handle this... Especially the style is important. In the 2.12 version loading label style is quiet tricky...

Comment: Either make 2 copies of the shapefile and merge changes to a master version (can be one of the files) or use a database postgres would be recommended.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to clarify what "work on" means.  If you mean "add rows", then the answer is "Yes, if the OS permits, and you don't mind losing all your work on a recurring basis, and corrupting the entire shapefile frequently." Actually, that same answer applies to most meanings.  Shapefiles (and dBase files) were never designed for multi-writer access, and even one-writer/multiple-reader use will occasionally result in application crash.

Comment: You are right, @Vince, that question was a little vague. I actually meant adding rows, editing the Attribute Table, etc. And I supposed that shapes were not made for multi-writer access, but we wanted to be sure that we didn't miss a change we just don't see. So why not ask experts. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**You *can*, but whoever commits changes last "wins".**

In a small office environment, this might be a reasonable solution. If there are only two of you, you work near each other, and you don't need to both be editing the same file(s) most of the time, it might be easiest to just say "Hey, I'm editing the blah shapefile now." Do your work, write changes to disk, and turn off editing.

The problem is refreshing your display. I tested with QGIS 2.12 on Linux and Windows. Many applications in Linux will just reload a file when they detects changes on disk. If I edit the shapefile in Windows, changes were reflected in the Linux display if

1. the layer was not in edit mode, or
2. the layer was in edit mode but no edits had yet been made.

The reverse (Linux edits to Windows display) was more problematic. Prior to editing the file, changes would appear in Windows, until the file was turned on for editing. After that the layer would not refresh, even when editing was turned off. The only way to get the new geometries was to remove and re-add the layer.

Note that this was based on limited testing. Since this is not a typical use case, this is probably not a "feature" so much as an accidental functionality which is OS-dependent.

If you need real version control (in the case of several users, distributed users, or constant edits to the same data source), there are two main options to consider. If your data *have to* remain in shapefile, you could look into [GeoGig](http://geogig.org/). If your data do not have to be be in shapefile, you should consider switching to PostGIS and using Oslandia's [versioning plugin](http://www.oslandia.com/qgis-versioning-plugin-en.html).

Comment: Probably highly dependent on the specific shared file system system that is in use too.

Comment: A race condition could cause one editor's shp and other's shx and dbf to be kept, which could cause serious application error (possibly delayed to next opening).  All-in all, there is significant probability for catastrophic data loss.

Comment: Thank you, Lee Hachadoorian. It really is a small office and the two working on the data are sitting next to each other, so I guess they will go on with simply splitting the data. I will talk to them about GeoGig and PostGIS, if these are a desirable alternatives for them.